# How do I manually send my C++ files to GitHub instead of pushing and then succesfully recompiling after downloading from GitHub? Standard practice?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I compile a simple Hello World program in Visual Studio. Then I manually place the **Hello World.sln, Hello World.vcxproj, Hello World.vcxproj.filters, Hello World.vcxproj.user, Hello World.cpp** files to a GitHub repository. Then I download the zip file from the repository and extract all the files into a folder under "repos" file of Visual Studio where new projects are added. Here unlike projects I manually create where I could click their sln file and the code will load perfectly, when I click the sln file of a downloaded zip file C++ existing project from GitHub errors occur. The first error is  "One or more projects in the solution were not loaded correctly." and the error box says "main\Hellow World\Hellow World.vcxproj" could not be found although it literally is in the folder.
What am I doing wrong here? 
Is pushing files to GitHub manually standard practice, because if I push using the Visual Studio Push utility methods that automatically creates a repository, and I download that zip file, and click the sln the code works and loads fine although the files are literally the same previously.

Comment: what's wrong with `git pull`, `git push`? Why does `zip` need to be involved at all?

Comment: many problems such as offline issues, no knowledge of Git, beginner user etc

Comment: Is the solution referring to project files using absolute paths?

Comment: use sourcetree or so. it has git console

Comment: Remy Lebeau has the answer I was looking for. Apparently I did not recreate the folder structure right. First I have to create an alias of the project in Documents with same name. Then inside that folder I have to copy the sln file there. Then copy the Project folder from VS to the Documents Folder. Delete the Debug folder inside there. This worked. The absolute paths actually matters. Thanks.